# SQL - Query log from Users table

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

Based on the following example : (it is a "QueryLog" table, this table store interactions between a user and two different products N and R):

---

```
Id         Date             UserID      Product
--------------------------------------------------
0  2013-06-09 14:50:24.000   100           N
1  2013-06-09 15:27:23.000   100           N
2  2013-06-09 15:29:23.000   100           N
3  2013-06-17 15:31:23.000   100           N
4  2013-06-17 15:32:23.000   100           N
5  2014-05-19 15:30:23.000   250           N
6  2014-07-19 15:27:23.000   250           N
7  2014-07-19 15:27:23.000   333           R
8  2014-08-19 15:27:23.000   333           R
```

### Expected results :

```
Count
-----
1
```

(Only UserID 250 is inside my criteria)

If one user interacts 10 times with the product in only one month, he's not in my criteria.

### To resume, I am looking for :

The Number of distinct users that had interactions with product N on at least more than one month (what ever the number of interactions this user may have had during a single month)

This is the code I've tried:

```
select distinct v.UserID, v.mois , v.annee
from 
(select c.UserID , c. mois, c.annee, COUNT(c.UserID) as frequence

from

(
    SELECT 
    datepart(month,[DATE]) as mois,
    datepart(YEAR,[DATE]) as annee ,
    Username,
    UserID,
    Product

    FROM QueryLog 
    where Product = 'N'

 ) c

group by c.UserID, c.annee, c.mois
) v
group by v.UserID, v.mois, v.annee
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Id int, [Date] datetime, UserID int, Product char(1))

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (0,'2013-06-09 14:50:24',100 ,'N')
,(1,'2013-06-09 15:27:23',100 ,'N')
,(2,'2013-06-09 15:29:23',100 ,'N')
,(3,'2013-06-17 15:31:23',100 ,'N')
,(4,'2013-06-17 15:32:23',100 ,'N')
,(5,'2014-05-19 15:30:23',250 ,'N')
,(6,'2014-07-19 15:27:23',250 ,'N')
,(7,'2014-07-19 15:27:23',333 ,'R')
,(8,'2014-08-19 15:27:23',333 ,'R')

;WITH MultiMonthUsers AS
(
    select
        UserID
        FROM (select
                  UserID 
                  FROM @YourTable 
                  WHERE product='N' 
                  GROUP BY UserID, YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]) 
             )dt2
        GROUP BY UserID 
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MultiMonthUsers
```

Depending on number of rows and indexes, this will run slow.  Using `YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date])` will prevent any index usage.

Comment: Converting varchar to date time created an out of bound value :s

Comment: I tried something else : SELECT
    c.Username,  COUNT(*)
FROM
    (select
 distinct Username,DATEPART(MONTH, Date) as mois, DATEPART(YEAR, Date) as annee 
FROM QueryLog
where Product='N'
) c
GROUP BY
    Username
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
    order by Username

Comment: I finally found a solution. this request works in my case.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, but I need a better dataset to test with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    --roll all month/user records into single row
    SELECT UserID, datediff(month 0, [date]) As MonthGroup
    FROM QueryLog
    WHERE Product='N'
    GROUP BY datediff(month 0, [date]), UserId
) t
-- look for users with multiple rows
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(UserID) > 1
```

Seems like there should be a way to roll this up further, to avoid the need for the nested select.